# How to Retain The Evaluation Score of kfold using cross_val_score()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I want to understand  **kfold** more clearly and how to choose the best model after it is implemented as a cross-validation method.

According to this source: `https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/` the steps to carry out kfold are:

1. Shuffle the dataset randomly
2. Split the dataset into k groups
3. For each unique group:

   - Take the group as a hold out or test data set
   - Take the remaining groups as a training data set
   - Fit a model on the training set and evaluate it on the test set
   - Retain the evaluation score and discard the model

4.Summarize the skill of the model using the sample of model evaluation scores

However, I have a question in relation to this process.

> what is **Retain the evaluation score**  and **discard the model** supposed to mean? how do you do it?

After my research, I believe it may have to do with the sklearn method `cross_val_score()`, but when I try to implement it, by passing my `model` to it, it throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 797, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temporary.py", line 187, in <module>
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X_test, y_test, cv=kf,scoring="accuracy")
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 390, in cross_val_score
    error_score=error_score)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 236, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1004, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 808, in dispatch_one_batch
    islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 236, in <genexpr>
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 67, in clone
    % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x00000267F9C851C8>' (type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

According to the documentation,https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html, the first argument for `cross_val_score()` must be an estimator, which they define as "estimator object implementing ‘fit’.The object to use to fit the data."

Therefore, I can't understand the exception.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization(weights=None, epsilon=1e-06, momentum=0.9))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())

from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,cross_val_score

kf = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=None, shuffle=True)
print(kf)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
     X_train, X_test = data[train_index], data[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = labels[train_index], labels[test_index] 


Adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam,
                       loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                       metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                            epochs=15, 
                            batch_size=32,
                            verbose=1,  
                            callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                            validation_data=(X_test, y_test)
                       )


scores = cross_val_score(model, X_test, y_test, cv=kf,scoring="accuracy")
print(scores)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Please take into consideration I am not a data scientist or a developer.

Answer (score 0):

> what is Retain the evaluation score and discard the model supposed to
>   mean?

Retain the evaluation means to save the evaluation of the actual model tested in the CV iteration, to just save it in memory to compare with the next evaluations.

> how do you do it?

You could use the cross_val_score() of sklearn when using sklearn algorithms, but you are working with keras, so you will need to work with the class KFold, have a look to this [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanie04736/simple-keras-model-with-k-fold-cross-validation), it shows the implementation you need. There are a lot of examples like this in the internet, just pick the one that you understand the most.

> Therefore, I can't understand the exception.

The cross_val_score() accepts an estimator as a first parameter. What is an estimator? According to the documentation, an estimator is a class that implements has a defined structure, following [this documentation.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimators)

As you can see, your keras model does not implement a part of the structure, so you get the error: *it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.*